# How to get all select elements having their with multiple selection criteria, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get all dropdowns having on the basis of multiple attributes name and value.
`$('input[name="ABC"][value="-1"]')` this expression seems to work, but for drop downs this doesn't seems working.

```
<select name="department"  />
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
</select>
alert($("select[name=department][value=-1]").length);
```

gives 0 in alert box.

refer to this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/8QBH7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8QBH7/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($("select[name=department] option[value=-1]").length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the query you're looking for:

```
$("select[name='department'] option[value=-1]")
```

See [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8QBH7/2/)

**Edit** based on your feedback I think you want to use the selected pseudo class. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QBH7/7/)

```
alert($("select[name=department] :selected").val());
$("select").on("change",function(){
    alert($("select[name=department] :selected").val());
});
```

Comment: But Next time when I change the value this query doesn't work.
See Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/8QBH7/6/